# Find the names of the suppliers who supply all the parts in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by, count

I have three tables:

```
SPB (ID, Part, Supplier), Suppliers (ID, Name), Parts (ID, Part)
```

I want to find the names of the suppliers who supply all the parts in MS Access.

This code does not work properly:

```
SELECT Suppliers.ID, Parts.ID
FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN (Parts INNER JOIN SPB ON Parts.ID = SPB.Part) ON Suppliers.ID = SPB.Supplier
WHERE 
 SPB.Part IN 
 (SELECT SPB.Part
 FROM SPB
 WHERE Suppliers.ID = SPB.Supplier)
AND
 SPB.Part IN 
 (SELECT Parts.ID
 FROM Parts
 WHERE Parts.ID)
```

What could be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of `Suppliers` and `Parts` and a `LEFT` join to `SPB`.
Then you group by supplier and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT t.supplierID, t.name
FROM (
  SELECT s.ID AS supplierID, s.name, p.Id AS part_ID
  FROM Suppliers AS s, Parts AS p
) AS t LEFT JOIN SPB AS b ON b.Supplier = t.supplierID AND b.Part = t.part_ID
GROUP BY t.supplierID, t.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(b.Part)
```

Comment: Clean solutions with different joins. So good.

Comment: @Kosarar your requirement is to return the names of the suppliers. This is why I join to suppliers also.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that SPB has one row per supplier/part pair, then you can count:

```
select supplier
from spb
group by supplier
having count(*) = (select count(*) from parts);
```

If you can have duplicate supplier/part pairs, then just remove duplicates before checking:

```
select supplier
from (select distinct supplier, part
      from spb
     ) as sp
group by supplier
having count(*) = (select count(*) from parts);
```

Comment: Very witty. "Boil down."